# How to log web errors on Asp.Net as Fiddler Request File

Tags: asp.net, logging, error-handling, fiddler, replay

Background:
On our asp.net web application we are saving error information (ex.Message, Stack Trace, User Id etc) on to our database.
So periodically we go back and try to reproduce the same error on our test servers.

Problem:
Sometimes, only these logs are not helping enough to solve issue because people may have different cookie information, user agent etc..

Possible Solution: 
We are thinking that if there is an error, save entire post request as Fiddler Request file.
So on fiddler we will load this file and Replay. It will send all related WebForms Cookies Headers etc.. So we will be pretty close that what action users are performing. as ajax, get or post request.

Question:
It is an ideal solution for our issue?
If yes, will be there easy way to save that information as "Fiddler Request File"
or we should write our own class to format request information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logs actually had all of the information required, you could save the request as a SAZ file easily for replay. But as far as I know, most logs don't have all of the information in the request. You might look at http://code.google.com/p/elmah/, which has the ability to generate Fiddler .SAZ files.